Two cross-join are giving a duplicate result with two separate values
I have table XYZ with following data
 Id  Name   ssids
 1    a1    1,2
 2    a2    3
 3    a3    4
 4    a4    5

I am using cross-apply with two separated values and getting the same result, but it is causing duplicates.
And I don't want to use distinct here. I just want to know what's wrong with the below query.
declare @Paravalue varchar(500)='1,2,3'

select t.*
from XYZ  t
cross apply string_split(t.ssids, ',') ColumnIds
cross apply string_split(@Paravalue, ',') paraId
where paraId.value = ColumnIds.value 

For above query getting output like below
 Id  Name   ssids
 1    a1    1,2
 1    a1    1,2
 2    a2    3

But I want result below without duplicate and I don't want to use distinct.
Id  Name   ssids
1    a1    1,2
2    a2    3


This is expected, 1 is in 1,2 and 2 is in 1,2 so you get 2 rows; one for each value. The real problem is you are storing delimited data in your database; why not normalise your design?

Also, those are APPLYs, not JOINs.

Simply SELECT DISTINCT?

Is there any way to achieve this and this already design by long ago can you please suggest. @ThomA

I have already mention don't want to use distinct here, can you please alternative solution. @jarlh

If you want to avoid SELECT DISTINCT, follow ThomA's advice and redesign your schema.

Use an EXISTS instead? Stop kicking the can down the road and fix the design?

Can you share full query will understand much better. @ThomA

The documentation has a lot of examples; what about those did you not understand so i can try to elaborate.

The sql goes: select * from XYZ  t where exists(select 1 from <your string split stuff and where>)

can you share full query because using two comma separated values. @siggemannen

Are you trying anything or just doing the "send me teh codez" question? select * from XYZ  t where exists(select 1 from string_split(t.ssids, ',') ColumnIds cross apply string_split(@Paravalue, ',') paraId where paraId.value=ColumnIds.value) perhaps

"can you share full query because using two comma separated values" if you look at your question , you'll see that the FROM  and WHERE , for two comma separated values, which you used in the EXISTS is actually there in your question.

What is the reason you don't want to use DISTINCT? Its silly to hamstring us of totally good solutions unless you have a very good reason.

Your query working fine thanks. @siggemannen

Rather than duplicating the data via cross apply just match the exploded results against the input parameter:
I was originally thinking OP wanted to see a list of which values matched:
declare @Paravalue varchar(500) = '1,2,3'
select t.*, ColumnIds.value /* extra column that is not duplicated */
from XYZ t cross apply string_split(t.ssids, ',') ColumnIds
where ColumnIds.value in (
    select paraId.value from string_split(@Paravalue, ',') paraId
);

Pushing the match into a subquery with intersect will match without any duplication of rows:
declare @Paravalue varchar(500)='1,2,3'
select * from t
where exists (
    select value from string_split(ssids, ',')
    intersect
    select value from string_split(@Paravalue, ',')
);

https://dbfiddle.uk/OkQW7ZWd
If you have a lot of rows I don't know if this query plan is worse than just using distinct though.

Getting again duplicates records. @shawnt00

@user3754858 I misunderstood what you wanted. Perhaps the update will work better.
